# What is a String ^ in Windows Forms? Any Chance I can convert it to a normal string?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

So I am programming with windows forms applications in Visual studios and I want to get the text from a text box and do stuff with it. It says that the text is a String ^. First of all what does the ^ mean? It also won't let me use that as a normal string so can i convert it to a normal string and vice-versa?

Comment: If you're using C++ with Windows Forms then you're using C++/CLI, I would read up on that as it is very different from vanilla C++.

Comment: Congratulations! You've been falling into the _"c++ shark tank"_ successfully. Re-tag your question properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).  A `String^` is a [handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08%28VS.80%29.aspx) to a managed `System::String` instance.

The best way to convert is to use the built in marshaling library:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

// given System::String^ managedString
std::string normalString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managedString);
```

Comment: Interesting! I havent heard of the marshaling library before. That worked. How would I then convert from string back to a managed String?

Comment: @user3164112 Just use `marshal_as<String^>(nativeStringOrCharPtr)`

Comment: Is there potential for a lossy conversion going to an std::string instead of an std::wstring?

Comment: @GregD Yes.  You can go to a `std::wstring` as well, though, and avoid that.